# usage of c_iflag/c_oflag/c_cflag bits defined in termios.h

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, termios

I'm curious why c_iflag/c_oflag/c_cflag bits defined in termios.h are decimal, while code is doing bit-wise operation using those defines. for example,

`#define OCRNL 0000010`

then OCRNL has two bits set, then how to use it in bit-wise operation?

Comment: `0000010` is not *decimal* but is **octal** notation (base 8).

Comment: Even if something is defined in decimal, what is preventing anyone from bit-wise operations?

Comment: Thanks Basile and Duck, didn't realize it is octal number, all make sense now.